# Creating custom library of WIX dialogs

Tags: wix

I have created an installer using my own custom dialogs, however I am now moving on to create many more setups that will use many of the dialogs I have already created. My question is does anyone know of any tutorials or anything that could help me create a dialog library.

Ideally I would like to have a custom dialog library that can be used by multiple installers, but that each installer could select which of the dialogs it needs. Something like WIX uses where you could use `<UIRef Id="CustomDialogs" />` and in every WIX setup I could customize it so that I only select the dialog I need for that certain setup.

At the moment I am just copying the dialog to the new WIX setup project but I would ideally like to do it more efficiently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is add your Custom Dialogs to a .wixlib project which you can then reference in your setup project.

Comment: That easy? I thought it would have been more complex..Thanks..:)